# jquery two number inputs automatically recalculating each input if another is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, numbers

I'm good with html, but no so good with javascripting :(
I've searched all over stackoverflow and googled for it, but didn't found exactly what i need, only thing i found which is more or less close to what i need is http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/QWSQp/64/

But what i need is two inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="num1" maxlength="15" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" value="">
<input type="text" name="num2" maxlength="15" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" value="" >
```

Both are set with rule, that only numbers with only one DOT is available:

```
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
```

Now question, i have a **X value** which is incerted by php

```
<?=$eur_price ?>
```

Point is creating two inputs where one is quantity and second is total price, but each field could be edited and if one is edited, another should be recalculated.

Example:

> X=1.5 (set price) ... Num1=10 so Num2 would be calculated to 15
>
> X=1.5 (set price) ... Num2=6 so Num1 would be calculated to 4
> And so on...
> So you can set how many u need or how much u would like to spend...

Any help how to do it, or how to edit example which i found?

Comment: But your other input is read only

Comment: That's what i'm saying, the example which i found is with one read only input. but i need both of them to be edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Separate the responsibilities in your logic to reuse your code

- Create an event i.e: `calculate` and bind it to `num2`.
- Dispatch that event from `input` event of `num1`.

  > The first two step must be applied to element `num2`.
- Add `id` to your inputs for a better performance.
- Move your logic to accept numbers and one dot to the event `input`.

## Look at this code snippet

*With this approach you can trigger the event calculate from anywhere*

```js
const calculate = new Event('calculate');

let n1 = document.getElementById("num1");
let n2 = document.getElementById("num2");
let eurPrice = 1.5;

// -------- num1 logic ---------
n1.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
  this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');    
  n2.dispatchEvent(calculate);
});

n1.addEventListener('calculate', function(e) {
  this.value = (n2.value / eurPrice).toFixed(2);
});

// -------- num2 logic ---------
n2.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
  this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
  
  n1.dispatchEvent(calculate);
});

n2.addEventListener('calculate', function(e) {
  this.value = (n1.value * eurPrice).toFixed(2);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num1" name="num1" maxlength="15" value="">
<input type="text" id='num2' name="num2" maxlength="15" value="">
```

Comment: not working backward, if i change num2 field, num1 isn't changing

Answer (score 1):

If using addEventListener, you can do this with one event and just check if num1 or num2 has been changed, if num2 changed, calc num1, if num1 changed calc num2;

Here is a simple example below.

```js
const euro = 1.5;

const num1 = document.querySelector("[name=num1]");
const num2 = document.querySelector("[name=num2]")

document.body.addEventListener("input", function (evt) {
  if (evt.target === num1) {
    num2.value = (parseFloat(num1.value) * euro).toFixed(3);
  } else {
    num1.value = (parseFloat(num2.value) / euro).toFixed(3);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="num1" maxlength="15">
<input type="text" name="num2" maxlength="15">
```

Comment: @Keith excellent answer.  The only thing I'd suggest adding is testing for a numeric value to prevent a `NaN` calculation.

Comment: I've added rule i had: "oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"